# Multicopter MotorModel Plugin and PID Controller for UAV in ROS2

Tags: ros2

I am making an altitude and attitude controller for an unmanned aerial vehicle (UAV, drone) with Ignition Gazebo and ROS2. I use the multicopter motor model plugin to do this. I would like your help with an interesting situation I encountered:
When I give the command to go up to my model (drone) with the joystick, the model goes up and hover in the air as I expected. But all of a sudden the model falls to the ground. The model does not move upwards even if I send the ascend command. I think this situation is not caused by the controller I wrote. I would like to explain the reason for this graphically:

[image]

Above are two graphs with the same x-axis (Click on the link and you will see). In the graphic above, there are the target distance (setpoint), the location (measured) and the difference between the setpoint and the measured (error) for the model to go, and the velocity values ​​to go to the motors produced by the altitude controller in the graphic at the bottom. When the red graph is examined, while the controller is working correctly, that is, the model with reduced error reaches the desired (setpoint) position and drops down at a time.

When the controller graphic is examined at first, it seems to work properly, because as the error decreases (blue line in the upper graph), the velocity value that will go to the produced motors decreases. so I think the source of the problem is not the controller, but the gazebo world. Is there a factor in the gazebo world that I should pay attention to? For example, type of atmosphere, air pressure etc.

Thank you for your help,
Kind regards.

I changed the pid coefficients in the attitude controller. I observed that when the coefficients are 0, that is, when the attitude controller is disabled, the model hover in the air and falls suddenly again

Comment: Please change this link for the actual pictures

Comment: please insert the pictures into your post ... use the button that looks like mountains ... there is no reason to follow a link to see the pictures ... the question should be self contained

Comment: I insert pictures of graphs

Comment: Do you have a small example showing the problem that you can share? One thing to try is to echo the commands being set to the topic specified in `<commandSubTopic>` of the `MulticopterMotorModel`.